# Ionic Tabs - header root pages above tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i've the the following problem with the header (toolbar) position in the roots pages:

[image: Screenshot]

Why the headers root pages are located above the tabs ? i need to put them within childs page.

the code is so simply:

```
 tabs.html

<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" tabsLayout="icon-bottom" tabsHighlight=true>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"> 
 </ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>


tab1Root (home.html)

<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
   <div >
      <small> 
        this is the toolbar ...
      </small>
    </div>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
 <p>
This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
</p>
<p>
 Take a look at the <code>src/pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
 update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
 </ion-content>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have placed the `<ion-toolbar>` within an `<ion-header>` which will position it at the top (header) of the screen. Please see the Ionic Toolbar [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/).

Try placing it within `<ion-content>` instead.

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>this is the toolbar ...</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: @JoséRamírez can you mark it as the correct answer then?

Comment: I don't think this is the best answer, that would subject the header to the scroll area of ion-content. If you wanted the header locked under the tabs bar I don't think this would be correct. If I figure out a better solution I'll be back to post it.